# expected an identifier but instead found 'else'

Tags: javascript, debugging

hello im trying to make a "choose your own adventure" game but im getting this error. i cant seem to figure out how to fix this and any help would be appreciated 
here's the coding i have so far,

```
var age = prompt("how old are you?");

if (age > 10) {
    alert("you may proceed");
} else; {
    alert("I think you should leave, NOW");
}

alert(
    "you are in a small room sitting in a desk. there is a door right        behind you PLEASE NOTE the apocalypses has just started there are only a few people in your building alive think about finding a weapon"
);
var userawnser = prompt(
    "Do you 'type 1 to' examine the room or '2' exit through the door?"
);
if (userawnser = 1) {
    alert(
        "You see a stapler on your desk a bat by the door and a computer.You grab the bat"
    );
} else if (userawnser = 2); {
    alert(
        "you walk outside of you room and are surprise attacked by a zombie"
    );
    alert(
        "you attempt to get the zombie off but since it got you by surprise you are bitten in the back of the neck and join the undead army"
    );
    confirm(
        "never go places unprotected silly or your guts will be harvested again!"
    );
} else; {
    alert("that doesn't make any since!");
}
```

Comment: You have a typo (extra `;` after `else`). There are also many, many other problems with your code, such as using `=` instead of `==` (which will break the entire thing), severe lack of indentation, arbitrary whitespace, etc. I suggest you go find a good [JavaScript tutorial, such as MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: Use `==` when testing for equality, not `=`.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Don't put `;` right after `else` or the test clause in `if` statements.

Comment: `"that doesn't make any since!"` - Yes, exactly.

Comment: ok some of the errors there are just a typo/forum error what i first typed was much cleaner and better

Comment: I don't remember putting any simi-colins after either else in my original post i don't know how they got there but i didn't know about the = and == thank you for that but i know for a fact that in the sentences that it cuts ); of off  at that i did the sentences correctly i never skipped a single alert line alot of these errors here were never there when i posted it ex alert(

Comment: Ex: alert("You walk out of your room and are surprise attacked by a zombie"); was origonaly posted like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a semi-colon after the last `else`.

Consider the order of your answers. Suppose you want the user to be sent directly to the game when `userawnser == 1` (aka `true`). If `userawnser == 2` (aka "User exits the door"), then the code should notify the user that they cannot play.

Try my code snippet below:

```
var age = prompt("how old are you?");
var userawnser;
//----------------------------------------------
//answer >=10
if (age >= 10) {
    alert("you may proceed");
    alert("you are in a small room sitting in a desk. there is a door right behind you PLEASE NOTE the apocalypses has just started there are only a few people in your building alive think about finding a weapon");

    userawnser = prompt("Do you 'type 1 to' examine the room or '2' exit through the door?");

    if (userawnser == 1) {
        alert("You see a stapler on your desk a bat by the do`enter code here`or and a computer.You grab the bat");
    } else if (userawnser == 2) {
        alert("you walk outside of you room and are surprise attacked by a zombie");

        alert("you attempt to get the zombie off but since it got you by surprise you are bitten in the back of the neck and join the undead army");
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, what number you choice?");
    }

    var confirmNeverGo = confirm("never go places unprotected silly or your guts will be harvested again!");
    if (confirmNeverGo === false) {
        alert("that doesn't make any since!");
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------
//answer <=10(poor kid)
} else {
    alert("I think you should leave, NOW");
}
```

I encourage you to do more research on forums, so that you can understand how to do things. Dedicate yourself to clean-up your code. Do not get discouraged if it does not work at first.